# Send multiple emails at the same time with different payload sizes - Email received in wrong order using sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server, email, smtp, sp-send-dbmail

I am trying to send multiple emails using **sp_send_dbmail** at a time with different payload sizes. Email with smaller payload size receives earlier than the emails with greater payload. See following example:

```
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='ABC',
@recipients='xxx@gmail.com',
@subject='Test message - 1',
@body='This is the body of the test message.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.'

EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='ABC',
@recipients='xxx@gmail.com',
@subject='Test message - 2',
@body='This is the body of the test message.
Congrates Database Mail Received By you Successfully.'
```

Can anyone suggests how I receive the emails based on order I specify using the same sp_send_dbmail?

Comment: You don't have any control on the order the mail servers involved process your messages.

Comment: If you need to ensure ordered delivery, smtp is the wrong protocol.

Comment: We are using this sp_send_dbmail in several areas and not allowed to change it. Is there any hack that we can do to control it. Like, I think if we can increase payload size of the second email  in such a way that user wont see anything extra will fix this issue. But yes its not a practice. What do you say?

Comment: There is no way to "slow down" a message like chaining a weight to it's leg. As soon as your messages are picked up by [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) MTA, there is absolutely no way to influence the order in which your messages are received. As already stated, you need to pick a different protocol (like a message queue) for your messages if you need delivery in a guaranteed order.

Comment: I strongly suggest you re-think the actual problem you are trying to solve - what you currently ask cannot be achieved.